# Datagridview - Bind Comboboxcell to Dataset Row and show value?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datagridview

I'm binding my Datagridview to Dataset, and unfortunally one of the fields needs to be a Comboboxcell. If you set DataProperty Name to desired field of Dataset, nothing happens. And everything I tried just adds item in Comboboxcell, but cannot get It to display in cell properly. Is there any way to do both - get value from Dataset Row in Comboboxcell and display It ?

```
 Private da As OracleDataAdapter
 Private cbAs OracleCommandBuilder
 Private ds As DataSet

   Dim SQL As String = "SELECT Serial,Name,Surname,Country,City from MyTable WHERE ID_Table1=" _
                      & Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

     Try

        OracleConn() 'Connection to DB

        Dim cmd = New OracleCommand(SQL, OracleConn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
        cb = New OracleCommandBuilder(da)
        ds = New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)

        My_DGV.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        'This code here "successfully" adds item and shows It in comboboxcell 
         'when It's only 1 row in Dataset - when they are more rows, Datagridview gets 
         'duplicated rows and duplicated items in comboboxcell + only comboboxcell
         'value of 1st row is displayed.
         For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
             Dim someVar As Integer = Integer.Parse(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1).ToString())
             Column5.Items.Add(someVar)
             Dim CellBox As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = CType(My_DGV.Rows(0).Cells(0), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
             'Select Item
             CellBox.Value = someVar
         Next
```

I'm struggling with this one many days now, any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT (picture of my desired output on Form_Load):
[image]

1. get Dataset row value in field "Combobox" (that is "Serial" field from SQL query) and show that value in combobox, together with all fields which are just textbox fields (this part is allready working);
2. when user clicks on combobox, It will get loaded with items again (with "SELECT * from My Table") - this way user can select any other record from that table and save It into this "join table" Datagrid (on combobox select all other fields get filled automatically). It will update row or user will just add a new row in datagridview. I allready have this solution, I just need 1st part.

Comment: Typically a column which is a CBO uses the data from a different table as the datasource.  Each row becomes an item in the drop down, for instance {Small, Med, Lg, XLg} rows for picking a Widget size.  I cant tell what you are trying to do there

Comment: @Plutonix, this one is a bit complex design. Im trying to display field value in CBO from Dataset row, and then Im going to try fill that CBO with another items, and chosing those items will automatically change all rows. Imagine that you see some record in datagrid, and then by selecting some CBO item you see different record (its a join view for main form). That is my goal

Comment: It doesnt sound like that CBO should be in the grid.  If it impacts all the rows, why have more than one?

Comment: @Plutonix, no you missunderstood. 5 fields in a row, one of them combobox and its 1st column...when you select item from cbo, all fields in same row gets updated (only 1 row). Basically you select a whole record, insert it in a row and then you save this in a join table. Making cbo out of datagrid for this would mean that you would need to select a row first(blank or filled) and insert record there (because some records are allready joined, this is just an update records form) - which would be kind of strange...

Comment: Are you trying to so something like in the first comment.  You a Widget table; one of the columns is `Size`.  The contents of Size show in a CBO, you pick one and the value is saved to Widget?  If so the contents of Size would be the datasource for the cbo; it will save ValueMember of Size to Widget in place of the text

Comment: @Plutonix, yes something like that, If we understand each other. Difference is only that on Load I would give Size value of Dataset field. Then when I would click in CBO, items would get removed and replaced with whole new Dataset. When CBO picked, value of Size would change and all other rows....I'm actually investigating this option now, I found something that you can bind combobox in Datagrid textbox.

Comment: Ok, sorry I cannot make any sense out of that and the code in the post doesnt seem to match.  If the CBO maps a FK relationship why would the datasource get replaced?

Comment: @Plutonix, see my updated question, I pasted image with more precise description. I also changed my SQL query to make more sense. "Serial" is the field value in DB that needs to be added in comboboxcell.

Comment: In part, what you describe is a little like the classic header-detail view, but what do you mean by a "join table"?  Fetching rows from one table to copy into another indicates a serious flaw in the design.  The point of relationships in dbs is to avoid repeating data

Comment: @Plutonix, join table - it joins records from 2 tables, it has both id of them in it. Datagrid shows 4 fields of 1st table (retrieved by id in join table) + unique field of join table. So, whatever you update in datagrid it should be updated only in join table and not in those 2 tables. Design like that is because user must see at least 3 fields from 1st table since records are mostly simmillar, so you can distinguish them only by seeing more fields of each record. I can't think of any better design like this that would include  less clicking over the form...

Comment: Ok, thats called an [Associative Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) "join table" is listed there, but I have never heard the term.  If you just need to create an association for a new record and the data starts in textboxes, dont you just need a CBO for them to pick the associated item?  I dont see where a DGV makes anything simpler or clarifies things unless you are creating associations for existing items.